# navigation div hidden under images after using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a side bar navigation that appears once you scroll down 300px. However when  applying it to my work the navigation doesnt appear. But when working in jsfiddle it appears correctly. So I dont know if its been hidden under images that are on my pc but I just cant seem to figure out why it is below everything.

So the here is the code in question.

```
       <div id="cbp-fbscroller" class="cbp-fbscroller">
            <nav style="display:none;">
                <a href="#fbsection1" class="cbp-fbcurrent">Section 1</a>
                <a href="#fbsection2">Section 2</a>
                <a href="#fbsection3">Section 3</a>
                <a href="#fbsection4">Section 4</a>
                <a href="#fbsection5">Section 5</a>
            </nav>
            <section id="fbsection1"></section>
            <section id="fbsection2"></section>
            <section id="fbsection3"></section>
            <section id="fbsection4"></section>
            <section id="fbsection5"></section>
        </div>
```

```
.cbp-fbscroller > nav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    right: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    width: 26px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```
 $(window).on('scroll', function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 900) {
       $('.cbp-fbscroller nav').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
       $('.cbp-fbscroller nav').fadeOut('slow');
    }

  });
```

Now here are two fiddles. One is basically just a code dump that I did to see if it was something wrong my side, but the navigation appear correctly in the fiddle and seems to be hidden under an image when actually working with all the correct images etc. Then the other fiddle is a more simplified version that works normally.

Simple: http://jsfiddle.net/6oaxt61a/20/

Code Dump: http://jsfiddle.net/nwp1yv0s/3/

Both navigations work just when applying it it seems to be stuck under something.

Comment: Its tough to tell without being able to see your full html with images. You have positioned the nav high enough with a z-index of "9999", so your CSS should be fine. 

If you load the page in chrome, with the element inspector on, while viewing the "console" tab....do you see an error? If so post that here.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ scrollfadein.js:1

Comment: "$" is defined within the jQuery library, which means you are running scrollfadein.js before jQuery is running. 

Place the following script after calling jQuery:

<script src="js/scrollfadein.js"></script> 

So, the placement in your HTML should look like:

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scrollfadein.js"></script>

Comment: The reason it works in jsfiddle is because they load jQuery prior to running your code in the HTML box.

Comment: awesome ure a star m8! :) also had to move the ajax right at the bottom of my code on the html page as well as <script src="js/scrollfadein.js"></script> just above it  (you probably meant that anyways). Thanks for the help!

Comment: By the way. How do you know what specifically to link in terms of ajax? sorry for my ignorance, how does it exactly work, and how do you know when to use it?

Comment: If you are referring to the 'cbpFixedScrollLayout.init' function at the bottom of the html, you will always want your initialization function loading last...after jQuery and other plugins. The load sequence is critical for the scripts to run effectively. Always remember, jQuery library comes first, then your plugin scripts, and finally your initialization script that attaches to an element within your specific HTML. 

As far as AJAX and how it works in general, that would require reading a more in depth article than I can provide here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to post the solution from the discussion here.

The following script was loading before jQuery, therefore you received a "$ is not defined" error which prevented your navigation from loading.

```
<script src="js/scrollfadein.js"></script>
```

The solution was to load your scripts in the following sequence:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="js/scrollfadein.js"></script>
```